# What is this mixed mapGetters syntax?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have seen in [the documentation that `mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) can take either an object (for explicit local naming) or an array (for implicit naming) when mapping a store value to a local component's state. However the codebase I am working with uses an unfamiliar syntax where a string is mixed with an array.

```
computed() {
  ...mapGetters('User', ['userToken'])
}
```

What does this syntax mean?

Comment: Codebase is using [Vuex modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Your link is not the documentation, it's just examples. From the actual [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mapgetters)

> - mapGetters(namespace?: string, map: Array | Object): Object
>   Create component computed options that return the evaluated value of a getter. [Details](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper)
>
>   The first argument can optionally be a namespace string. [Details](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

So in your code, `User` is the namespace.